# Pedir dato desde FIREBIRD

Tags: sql, firebird

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de pedir datos desde firebird... se que se pide con la siguiente sintaxis de dos puntos y nombre :dato, pero quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de mostrarle al usuario como en forma de lista donde solo seleccione en vez de escribirlo desde la ventana que se le aparece.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
SELECT C.NOMBRE AS USUARIO, A.FECHA AS FECHA, A.FOLIO AS FOLIO, D.NOMBRE AS TARJETA, B.IMPORTE AS TOTAL, E.NOMBRE AS CAJA
FROM 
    DOCTOS_PV A
LEFT JOIN 
    DOCTOS_PV_COBROS B
ON 
    A.DOCTO_PV_ID = B.DOCTO_PV_ID
LEFT JOIN  
    CAJEROS C
ON 
    A.CAJERO_ID = C.CAJERO_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    FORMAS_COBRO D
ON 
    B.FORMA_COBRO_ID = D.FORMA_COBRO_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    CAJAS E
ON 
    A.CAJA_ID = E.CAJA_ID
WHERE
    FECHA = :F_FECHA
        AND D.NOMBRE = :FORMA_COBRO (aquí quisiera que le mostrara como una
    
     lista con varias formas de cobro)
        
AND E.NOMBRE = :CAJA
```

Comment: Firebird es un **motor de base de datos**, que actúa como servidor y usualmente corre como un servicio/demonio, por lo que no tiene una interfaz de usuario. Lo que pides es algo que usualmente se hace a nivel de la aplicación cliente que utiliza Firebird como almacén de datos, pero la respuesta realmente depende de la herramienta/lenguaje con la que estás haciendo esa aplicación y poco o nada que ver con Firebird como tal.

Comment: Si, es imposible como apenas estoy aprendiendo Microsip, viene un modulo llamado reporteador, pero no viene un combobox o algo parecido para hacerle una consulta, y quería saber si se podía desde una consulta desde la  base de datos, pero creo que no  se puede, igual muchas gracias, tampoco los de microsip dijeron que no existe una opción así en su reporteador, así que deje el reporte que el usuario escribiera tal cual el nombre. muchas gracias por responder.